# Is there any way to backup an iphone *including* passwords and such?

Tags: iphone, backup

My iphone 4 was backing up to the cloud. I got a 5, and did the entire restore process. I was irritated and inconvenienced to discover that my email account passwords and my google 2-step verification tokens in the google authenticator app did not come back from the backup. I had to re-enter account passwords, and then tear down and re-set-up the google authenticator tokens.

Aside from my mild pique that the Apple person who sold me the phone neglected to mention this little bit of entertainment, I'm left wondering: is there any way to get backups to *include* this stuff? Do itunes backups include this stuff, so that I'd be happier if I switched from cloud to itunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you make an encrypted backup using iTunes it will include passwords.

Comment: Can anyone improve on 'i believe'?

Comment: I've never done this myself, but here's a source: http://lifehacker.com/5799274/encrypt-your-iphone-backups-for-convenience-not-just-security.  Sorry that it's Gizmodo.

Comment: Note that iCloud backups are always encrypted: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136